# Change Label.Text in nested Master Pages from Content on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

This is the situation. I have a masterpage Site.
Master that contains another masterpage Shop.Master.
Inside Shop.Master there is a ContentPlaceHolder that loads Something.aspx .
Inside the top-masterpage there is a label `[lblText]` present.
The page Something.aspx contains a textbox `[boxInput]` and a button `[btnButton]`.
What I'm trying to accomplish is when I click button `[btnButton]` the value `lblText.Text` is being set to the content of `[boxInput]`.

Here is an abstract view of the problem.
[image]

I hope you guys can help me out. Google isn't being a great help this time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: thx for fast reply, but I allready checked that link.
I still can't figure out how to do it in nested masterpages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this. may it helps

```
     ContentPlaceHolder plchldr= this.Master.Master.FindControl("YourMainMasterContentID") as ContentPlaceHolder;
            Label lbl = plchldr.FindControl("lblText") as Label;
             if(lbl !=null)
             { 
               lbl.Text="SomeText"
             }
```

Comment: Can you tell me what `"MainContent"` is in the `FindControl()`?

Comment: your ConentPlaceHolder for the ParentMaster

Answer (score 1):

This is generally a bit of a weird problem. The only way I've been able to solve this in the past, is something like:

```
((MasterPageType)this.Master).lblText = "Whatever";
```

You may need to bubble-up two master pages, as per your specific situation:

```
((MasterPageRootType)((MasterPageType)this.Master).Master).lblText = "Whatever";
```

This will obviously fail if you change your Masterpage to be of a different type.

(I's been ages since I did WebForms, so forgive me if this isn't 100%)